# Complex Number (Angle)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

The complex number $z$ is given by $z=-2+2i$

1. Find the modulus and argument of $z$
2. Write down the modulus and argument of $\dfrac{1}{z}$
3. Show on an Argand diagram the points A,B and C representing the complex numbers $z$, $\dfrac{1}{z}$ and $z+\dfrac{1}{z}$ respectively.
4. State the value of $\angle ACB$.

For 1. I got the modulus of $z=2\sqrt{2}$ and $\arg(z)=2.356\,\text{rad}$

For 2. I got the modulus of $\dfrac{1}{z}=\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}$ and $\arg\left(\dfrac{1}{z}\right)=-2.356\,\text{rad}$.

How to solve question 4.?

Comment: Draw a triangle and use some geometry/trig?

Comment: Note also that the angle can be expressed exactly as a rational multiple of $\pi$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a geometric approach, which is suitable for the Argand plane.

1. The argument of $z$ is $\frac 34\pi$, which equals the value you gave as a decimal. That means the angle from the origin to point A representing $z$ is $45°$ *up* from the negative $x$-axis.

[image]

2. The argument of $\frac 1z$ is $-\frac 34\pi$, which equals the value you gave as a decimal. That means the angle from the origin to point B representing $\frac 1z$ is $45°$ *down* from the negative $x$-axis. Note that angle between the vectors from the origin to $A$ and $B$ is $45°+45°=90°$. Those vectors are perpendicular.
3. By vector addition in the plane, the vector from $A$ ($z$) to $C$ ($z+\frac 1z$) is parallel to the vector from the origin to $B$ ($\frac 1z$) and has the same length. Hence, the polygon $OACB$ is a rectangle.
4. The rectangle means that $\angle ACB=90°=\frac{\pi}2$.

---

A numeric approach could be done by using the dot product on the relevant vectors. But the geometric approach above should be sufficient.

Comment: What program do you use to plot the points ?

Comment: Looks like Geogebra.

Comment: @Mathxx: Yes, that is Geogebra. I haven't figured out just how to size and export my image to get maximum quality in this site.

Comment: It's already in very good quality, thanks !